# 8-way motorized lab valve control

Tags: power-supply

We do have couple of old Valves [Pharmacia IMV-8](http://www.gelifesciences.co.jp/tech_support/manual/pdf/56115337.pdf) but just a few controllers lying around in our labs. I would like to control these valves either via an Arduino or Raspberry. The manual states following protocol for external control:

[image]
[image]

I would like to buy a programmable power supply because I do not have time to dig into this topic and make myself one. But I had no success with searching the web. Probably, because I do not know the proper terminology.

Do you know some solutions/devices ? If there exist a simple amplifier/controller which just have to be soldered onto a board, that would be fine too.

To be more precice: I do need 24 V DC power supply and would like to be able to provide variable current to pin 2 (>30 mA) and 6 (1 A and 300 mA). Ideally, it is some kind of board which is programmable and can be connected to an Arduino or Pi.

I do not really know how the valve operates. I guess I have to try what happens If I provide a current of ~ 50 mA to pin 2 and 1 A to pin 6 (probably a pulse followed by a period of 300 mA). I am used to provide Voltage signals but not currents. So I do not really know how to start. The motor moves the slit from position to position (radial flow)

[image]

Comment: Above data are just too little to understand how the valve operartes and how it should work.

Comment: Edit the title to something like '8-way motorized lab valve control' or similar that will give a clue to the subject (for the benefit of others). As you can see the 'programmable power supply' isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pharmacia IMV-8](http://www.gelifesciences.co.jp/tech_support/manual/pdf/56115337.pdf) is an 8-way selector valve. Reading the data sheet it should work as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN5a8H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Test circuit.*

- Wire up as shown. The valve GND and 24 V common and 5 V common should all be connected together.
- Switch on the power.
- Press the start switch. The valve should run anti-clockwise. The LED should blink every time the valve moves into a valid position. The position number can be read from the valve LEDs.
- Release the button when the desired position is reached.

---

**Micro control**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh4pfo.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Interfacing with micro.*

The data sheet says 'a 10 kΩ pull-up resistor to +5 V must be connected to pins 3, 7, 8 and 9'. Use the internal pull-ups of your micro for this and you won't need external components.

---

**Understanding the data sheet**

- **Pin 1**: +24 V power.
- **Pin 2**: if pulled high by the 10k pull-up resistor the valve will rotate anti-clockwise. If shorted to GND it will rotate clockwise. The shorting device will carry 30 mA.
- **Pin 3**: open-collector transistor outputs This is open-circuit when out of position (off) and connected to GND when in-position (active).
- **Pin 4**: GND / negative for both the 24 V motor and 5 V logic signals.
- **Pin 5**: +5 V supply for the logic.
- **Pin 6**: probably the motor negative wire. The motor + is connected to +24V. Connect to GND to start. The motor will draw 1 A when starting, falling to 0.3 A when it gets up to speed. All you have to do is supply 24 V. The data sheet says 'short to pin 1 to stop'. Effectively this is connecting both ends of the motor together which will short circuit the motor to give a dynamic brake for rapid stop.
- **Pin 7, 8 and 9**: valve address binary code. These work the same as pin 3.

---

**Pseudo code**

```
int moveTo; // desired stop position
int posn;   // actual position

// convert the three binary bits into decimal value
posn = 0;
if(bit0) {posn += 1;}
if(bit1) {posn += 2;}
if(bit2) {posn += 4;}

// motor control
if((moveTo != posn) || !posnMatch) {
    motorRun = true;
} else {
    motorRun = false;
}
```

I have assumed positive logic for clarity. The valve outputs are active low so you may need to invert all the input signals. e.g., if(!bit0){ ...

Comment: Great. Thank you. That helps me with the first steps. So I do not have to take care of the current at pin 9. Great news. I did not understand the exact meaning of the text.

Comment: Guessing what your unfinished comment is asking: There is no intelligence in the valve. You have to control the motor and monitor POSN MATCH _and_ the binary code and stop the motor when it reaches _exactly_ the desired position. I presume the binary code will be on for, say, ±10° of position but that POSN MATCH will be much tighter - say ±2°. This also explains why they don't want you to let the motor coast to a stop and over-run - they recommend shorting it for immediate stop.

Comment: Ahem, sorry. Yes that was the question. If I have to monitor either POSN MATCH or the binary code.

Comment: Pseudo-code added. It may help.

Comment: Now looking at it, I see how simple this task is. Actually, I think that I do have everything at home. I will use a relais-shield and a 24 V power supply. The only thing left is to do the wiring. Would it be wrong to connect pin 2 via a relais to GND without a transistor ? What is the Diode for ?

Comment: Pin 2 to ground is fine. Motor will run clockwise. Relays are highly inductive. Inductors like to keep current flowing constantly and give a high voltage kick when turned of suddenly. High voltage + little transistor - smoke. [Flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) eliminates 'flyback' (and keeps the smoke inside the transistor).

Comment: dark memories from school are coming back.